# Ubuntu Server 12.04 forked-daapd 5 minute time out issue

Tags: 12.04, server, daap

I have a server running ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and I have installed forked-daapd but i am having the issue where forked-daapd stops working after five minutes of use. Has anyone been able to get around this issue? I believe there is a fix for this but I haven't found a way to install that in ubuntu 12.04. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Prince

Comment: You have to tell us what you done. Like how you installed forked-daapd and which patch you tried. We can't read your mind and hasn't looked over your shoulder while you tried to fix this, you know. So please update your question with that information.

Comment: We may close this since it doesn't have enough information to answer, but if you answer @Anders's questions (edit your question to add the request info), please feel free to flag (and maybe also comment) to request this be reopened.